# Apache - disable single option override

Tags: apache, directoryindex

How do I **disable** single option **override** in specific folder in Apache? I'd like to force *DirectoryIndex* value in specific folder, so *DirectoryIndex* option in .htaccess of that folder will be ignored. I'd expect configuration should look somehow similar, but neither works:

```
<Directory "/home/me/www/symfonyProject1">
    DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
    AllowOverride -Indexes
</Directory>
```

or this

```
<Directory "/home/me/www/symfonyProject1">
    DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
    AllowOverride Options=-DirectoryIndex
</Directory>
```

Is this even possible? How could I achieve that?

Using: Apache/2.2.8 (Win32) & Windows 7 x64

Comment: Did you try `AllowOverride Options=-Indexes`? Why set `DirectoryIndex` if you want to disable it?

Comment: `AllowOverride Options=-Indexes` gives me 500. I've already clarified my purpose in question, I'd like to force custom DirecotryIndex value no matter what is set in *.htaccess* file.

Comment: Upgrade to Apache 2.4 and the solution may be [AllowOverrideList](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverridelist)?

Comment: @julp that looks promising, but 1) I want to write `AllowOverrideList` in negative way 2) I don't want to cause 500 if there is some option in .htaccess file, just ignore it

Comment: For 1) unfortunately you can't for now ; 2) have a look to `AllowOverride ... Nonfatal=Override` (still specific to Apache 2.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possiblility, even though it is definitely not kosher, is to let `.htaccess` be ignored by versioning system locally. Then you can change as you wish to adapt you instance.

In case you need to change original `.htaccess`, you must do following (for GIT):

1. backup your modified `.htaccess` file
2. Comment out line `.htaccess` in file `.git/info/exclude`
3. do `git checkout -- .htaccess` to retrieve original file
4. modifiy and commit changes
5. Uncomment `.htaccess` line in `.git/info/exclude`
6. Copy modified `.htaccess` from backup to working tree

Answer (score 0):

I did not get this working with the `<Directory>` tag in `httpd.conf` but it was working if I did the following:

In `/home/me/www/symfonyProject1` create a `.htaccess` file and put `DirectoryIndex app_dev.php` in it.

This should work as long as you `AllowOverride All` (Or more narrow if needed) in the parent configuration.

Comment: Thank you for advice, but I don't want to modify .htaccess file. It is versioned and used in production and there is already `DirectoryIndex app.php`

Comment: Hmm, I am **not sure** you can override the `.htaccess` file from the main config, unless you set the `AllowOverride` but than you can't override the option from the main config either. In development I would suggest you just swap the `.htaccess` file with a new one and let the production one be intact. As I wrote, I am not sure about the override though. Need to test it. :)